# PayPal: How to sanitize field values for dynamically created Encrypted Website Payments buttons?

Tags: python, paypal

We have successfully implemented in our Python+pyramid program Encrypted Website Payments for PayPal, except for a tiny detail: input sanitization. Namely, we would like to help the user by providing as much data as possible to the PayPal from our user database. Now, it occurred to me that a malicious user could change his name to 'Mr Hacker\nprice=0.00' or similar, and thus completely negate the security offered by EWP. I did try URL-encoding the values, but PayPal does not seem to decode the percent escapes in the file.

Our code is based on the django-paypal library; the library completely neglects this issue, outputting happily bare name=value pairs without any checks:

```
    plaintext = 'cert_id=%s\n' % CERT_ID
    for name, field in self.fields.iteritems():
        value = None
        if name in self.initial:
            value = self.initial[name]
        elif field.initial is not None:
            value = field.initial
        if value is not None:
            # @@@ Make this less hackish and put it in the widget.
            if name == "return_url":
                name = "return"
            plaintext += u'%s=%s\n' % (name, value)
    plaintext = plaintext.encode('utf-8')
```

So, how does one properly format the input for dynamically encrypted buttons? Or is there a better way to achieve similar functionality in Website Payments Standard to avoid this problem, yet as secure?

### Update

What we craft is a string with contents like

```
item_number=BASIC
p3=1
cmd=_xclick-subscriptions
business=business@business.com
src=1
item_name=Percent%20encoding%20and%20UTF-8:%20%C3%B6
charset=UTF-8
t3=M
a3=10.0
sra=1
cert_id=ABCDEFGHIJKLM
currency_code=EUR
```

and encrypt it for EWP; the user posts the form to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr. When the user clicks on the button, the PayPal page "Log in to complete your checkout" the item name displayed is "Percent%20encoding%20and%20UTF-8:%20%C3%B6". Thus, for EWP input it seems that percent encoding is not decoded.

Comment: Ah, I should mention we use PayPal solely for subscriptions / recurring payments so any solution that does not provide them is not acceptable, and the business is located in Finland which means some of the more advanced services are not available to us.

Comment: Can you show what you mean by *PayPal does not seem to decode the percent escapes in the file*? PayPal suggests that all values in NVPs be url encoded.

Answer (score 1):

You could filter out key-value pairs with regular expressions;

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'Mr Hacker\nprice=0.00\nsecurity=false'
>>> re.sub('[\n][^\s]+=[^\s]*', '', text)
'Mr Hacker'
```

Or even more simple, ditch everything after the first newline;

```
>>> text.splitlines()[0]
'Mr Hacker'
```

The latter *assumes* that the first line is correct, which might not be the case.

Comment: Yes, I can filter newline characters. That is what we do right now, we replace them with spaces, how about other characters that are unsafe? I am looking for an answer from credible/official sources, something that says "you can use all characters except newline" or "the list of not allowed characters in values is ..."

Comment: You'd have to ask paypal, I think. But it would surprise me if they _don't_ sanitize inputs!

Comment: Have a look at: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_NVPAPIOverview

Comment: NVP is not the same as Encrypted Website Payments. EWP dictates that name-value pairs be separated by newline, not &. Furthermore, as proven above, EWP does not support percent-escaping.